# If empty array being executed with a value in the array

Tags: php, arrays

Hi all I have a simple image uploading script for my website with a few checks to be taken before the image is uploaded. If I try to upload for instance a gif or a large file the correct error message will be displayed but the image will still continue to upload. Although this shouldn't be happening as for the error message to be displayed there would have to be a value in the array?
Any advice?

```
<?php
$message = "";
$errors = array();

if (isset($_POST['uploadImg'])) {
// getting data needed from the image
$image = $_FILES['image'];
$imageName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$imageTmpName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$imageSize = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$imageError = $_FILES['image']['error'];
$imageType = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$imageInfo = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$imageWidth = $imageInfo[0];
$imageHeight = $imageInfo[1];
// seperates the image name from the image extension
$getImageExt = explode('.', $imageName);
// puts all extensions to lowercase to prevent exceptions e.g. JPEG not     being accepted
$imageExt = strtolower(end($getImageExt));
// array containg the allowed file types
$allowed = array(
    'jpg',
    'jpeg',
    'png',
    'tiff'
);

// checks if the file extension exists in the array
if (!in_array($imageExt, $allowed)) {
$errors[ext] = "Invalid file format";
}



// checks if there are any errors with the image
if (!$imageError === 0) {
$errors[image] = "Error with your file";
}


// checks if the file size is less than 1MB
if (!$imageSize < 1000000) {
     $errors[size] = "File is to big";
}


// check if the image width is less than or equal to 1024px
if (!$imageWidth <= 1024) {
$errors[width] = "Image width is limited to 1024px for layout purposes";
}


// check if image  height is less than or equal to 768 pixels
if (!$imageHeight <= 768) {
$errors[height] = "Image height is limited to 768px for layout purposes";
}

 if (empty($errors)) {

// inserts the uploaded image into the 'images' directory
$imageDestination = 'images/' . $imageName;
move_uploaded_file($imageTmpName, $imageDestination);

} else {

$message = "Something Went Wrong";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't just rely in the extension of the file, as a user could have an incorrect extension for a file

Comment: You must not use the client supplied filename without validating it. After you fixed the bug that SpacePhoenix mentioned, clients can overwrite any file in any directory your webserver can write to by sending a filename like ../../../index.php. The best you can do is ignore the sent filename altogether and generate one out of thin air.

Comment: Anyone can send any amount of data that they want to your server unless your webserver specifically blocks them off after X amount of bytes - PHP is first called _after_ the file has been uploaded - it doesn't know the user even existed until then.

Answer (score 0):

Your keys in $error aren't wrapped in quotes. eg.

```
if (!in_array($imageExt, $allowed)) {
    $errors['ext'] = "Invalid file format";
}
// checks if there are any errors with the image
if (!$imageError === 0) {
    $errors['image'] = "Error with your file";
}
// checks if the file size is less than 1MB
if (!$imageSize < 1000000) {
     $errors['size'] = "File is to big";
}
// check if the image width is less than or equal to 1024px
if (!$imageWidth <= 1024) {
    $errors['width'] = "Image width is limited to 1024px for layout purposes";
}
// check if image  height is less than or equal to 768 pixels
if (!$imageHeight <= 768) {
    $errors['height'] = "Image height is limited to 768px for layout purposes";
}
```

That might fix your error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `!` from your comparisons.

Line `!$imageSize < 1000000` is treated like:

```
(!$imageSize) < 1000000
```

If your `$imageSize` is 500, `!$imageSize` is false and therefore is `0` as number.

Same with all other comparisons except `in_array` one.